# Tcsh: muting the "new process" output on the terminal

Tags: process, tcsh

I am writing a script in tcsh on Linux red hat (cannot use other shells due to back-compatibility issues in my environment)

If within my script I call a program cmd with an ampersand, then I will get an output on the terminal looking something like:

```
> cmd &
```

output:

```
[1] 20398
[terminal output from command cmd]
[1]  Done       cmd
```

My question is: how can I mute the two lines starting with [1], i.e. the lines related to the process spawning, so that they do not appear on the terminal?

Output redirect does not help because, I think, those terminal output lines are not coming from cmd, but from the operative system.

Thank you!